# extract files from tar using perl in windows

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to extract files from a tar file, but it can not extract all the file there are .ksh,.config,.txt,.param files. it is on;y extracting the .config file.

Could you please let me know how I can extract all files from that tar file. Also during extraction it is printing all the content of a file in command prompt I want to stop that.

**Code I am using:**

```
use Archive::Tar;

my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
$tar->read('tar file name');

$tar->extract;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Archive::Tar;

my $tar = Archive::Tar->new; # remove `()`

$tar->read('tar.tgz');
$tar->extract();
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Could you please let me know if I want to extract selected files in pre-defined directory I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I used `perldoc Archive::Tar` - it [informed](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html) me that the correct syntax is

```
use Archive::Tar;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;

$tar->read('origin.tgz');
$tar->extract();
```

Answer (score 0):

If extract() is called without parameters the entire contents of the archive are extracted (http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html)

```
use Archive::Tar;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
$tar->extract();
```

Please check if your tar archive really contains these *.ksh, *.txt and *.params files. You may use:

```
$tar->contains_file( $filename )
```